# System Resource Monitor/Graph

Tags: windows, taskmanager, resource-monitor

I'm looking for an app that does about the same thing at the Performance tab on Task Manager, but on a per-process basis and with more plotted values. At a minimum, I would like to be able to plot CPU and memory usage but it would be nice if it could plot:

- Network usage
- File system IO (per drive/share sub headings would be nice)
- Open file stream count
- [LSOF](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_lsof.htm) like stuff
- All the other stats that the Process tab can give you
- ... anything else ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows comes with perfmon which is pretty much exactly what you want. It has infinity different counters with different categories - also individual apps can register their own counters.

Comment: Nice to know. It bit "utilitarian" but gets most of the point.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Norm at FS Walker Hughes, he made this and published it on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/graphfx.aspx)

**What you exacly need is this => [processstudio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/processstudio.aspx)**

Both have full source code available.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'd try the them (they looks good) but it asks for a login :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use NAPI.